# Can somebody explain how we calculated the address of the structure member?

Tags: c

I run the below code and I got

0x106879018

0x106879030

I really do not understand how we get this address. If we have 6 ints.. this is 24 bytes..
But I am not sure where to go with it.

I will be really thankful for help!

```
struct one{
    int x[6];
    short y[12];
}a;


int main(){

    printf("%p \n", &a);
    printf("%p \n", &a.y);

}
```

Comment: It's in hexadecimal.

Comment: 0x106879030 - 0x106879018 *is* 24. What exactly confuses you?

Comment: @remyabel yes, and what? I do not know how 24 bytes converts in hexadecimal answer...

Comment: @KeithThompson isn't it 12

Comment: @Femx `0x106879030 - 0x106879018` is `0x18` or `24` in decimal.

Comment: C provides a function in `stddef.h` named `offsetof` that returns the offset in `bytes` of a member within a `struct` (or other type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Here is the arithmetic:

```
0x10687903016 - 0x10687901816 = 0x1816 == 2410
```

2) And here is the layout:

```
struct one{
    int x[6];     // bytes 0..23 (24 bytes)
    short y[12];  // bytes 24 .. 47 (next 24 bytes)
}a;
```